# Django Postgres Exclusion Constraint with ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, postgresql, exclusion-constraint

I would like to use Django Exclusion Constraint with ManyToManyField. Unfortunatelly, so far my efforts were futile.
This is my appointment model:

from django.contrib.postgres.constraints import ExclusionConstraint
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import DateTimeRangeField, RangeOperators

```
class Appointment:
    patients = models.ManyToManyField(Patient, related_name='appointments' , blank=True )     
    datetimerange = DateTimeRangeField(null=False, blank = False )
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, related_name='doctor_appointments') 

    class Meta: 
        constraints = [ 
            ExclusionConstraint(
                name='unique_doctor',
                expressions=[
                    ('datetimerange', RangeOperators.OVERLAPS),
                    ('doctor ', RangeOperators.EQUAL),

                ], 
            ), 
            ExclusionConstraint(
                name='unique_patients',
                expressions=[
                    ('datetimerange', RangeOperators.OVERLAPS),
                    ('patients', RangeOperators.CONTAINED_BY)
                
                ],
                condition= Q(is_archived=False) & Q(is_cancelled=False)                
        ) 
        ]
```

Unfortunatelly this doesn't work. The first constraint that references the Doctor works perfectly, but the second one gives me this error during migration:

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "patient_id" named in key does not exist

    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "patient_id" named in key does not exist
```

This has been bogging me for quite some time. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the constraint must be made on the `Appointment` model's table, however because `patients` is a M2M field, there is no column as the error message says. The relationship is based on an intermediate table which holds the foreign key.

**The upshot is that you can't do exactly what you want to do here.**

However, you could build this validation into the model's [`clean()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method.